# Convert text to upper case in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I have one custom object  field name Flight_Request_*c.Fields.From*_c where
Flight_Request is a custom object and  From__c is a text field

how it possible that when user type in from field it changes to Upper case

Please help me..

Comment: You can set this on update/insert trigger. So after user will push save button value will be changed to upper case.

Comment: Are you using a visualforce page?

Comment: @ Ryan i am not using visualforce page.

Comment: Why does it have to be upper case?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use workflows and field updates to change the case to UPPER

Workflow -> field update -> select obj, thien field. Choose formula and your formula = UPPER()  then activate it.

Comment: This would convert the field text to uppercase, but it won't convert it as the user types. Great idea, though; it probably requires the least amount of work, and it takes advantage of the platform nicely.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I assumed this is what he meant though

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript on the onkeyup attribute.

```
<apex:inputtext value="{!Widget__c.Name}" onkeyup="var u=this.value.toUpperCase();if(this.value!=u){this.value=u;}" />
```

This will work on [`<apex:inputfield>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputField.htm) components as well as [`<apex:inputtext>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputText.htm), if the `inputfield` contains a Visualforce field that accepts text.

Comment: @ Matthew dats fine but i am not using visualforce page.

Comment: There's a similar question by Anil D here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228780/is-it-possible-to-add-style-to-a-field-in-salesforce.