# How to clean up text fields in Salesforce without using APEX or Workflow

Tags: javascript, salesforce

The professional edition licence of Salesforce does not allow the use of APEX code or Workflow unless purchased separately.

I have a requirement to clean up text in Salesforce that was input via on a web form that I do not control. The client wants to fix any text with ALL CAPS or missing sentence capitalisation.

I've seen this answer on a this question [Is it possible to add style to a field in Salesforce?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10230267/466873) which uses javascript within a custom side bar component . It assumes that the transformation is to occur as the user types the data into the application. My requirement might allow for a custom salesforce button to invoke the action on the fields as the data will populated by an automated process.

Assuming I were to follow the same pattern I would have to find a way to reliably detect and fix bad formatting within a string.

Is there a good way to do this with javascript within salesforce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way to get closer to what I need thanks to a regular expression and the AJAX toolkit.

I have created a custom detail button that invokes javascript OnClick.

The code takes the current lead and searches the Description field for any strings of >2 characters that are uppercase, within the characther class [A-Z]. Each time it matches a string it will replace that string with a lowercase version of itself.

Once the string has been 'cleaned' the lead can be updated.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")} //adds the proper code for inclusion of AJAX toolkit
var url = parent.location.href; //string for the URL of the current page

var updateRecords = []; //array for holding records that this code will ultimately updated

  var re = new RegExp('[A-Z]{2,}', 'g');
  var inputString = "{!Lead.Description}";
  var matches = inputString.match(re);
  if(matches != null){
   for(var i = 0; i< matches.length;i++){
    inputString = inputString.replace(matches[i], matches[i].toLowerCase());
   }

  var update_Lead = new sforce.SObject("Lead"); //create a new sObject for storing updated record details
  update_Lead.Id ="{!Lead.Id}"; //set the Id of the selected Lead record
  update_Lead.Description = inputString;
  updateRecords.push(update_Lead); //add the updated record to our array

 }
 result = sforce.connection.update(updateRecords); //push the updated records back to Salesforce
 parent.location.href = url; //refresh the page
```

I based this code on some that I found [Salesforce: Custom Button to Execute JavaScript](http://www.interactiveties.com/b_execute_javascript_button.php)

It should be possible to amend this code to work on any Salesforce object and to work over a selection of fields. The code that does the replacement could be moved into a function to make this easier.